# mysql users can see stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, security, stored-procedures, privileges

example:
A non-super user has been granted execute on a procedure that inserts into table "a".  That user will see the database that table "a" is in with a "show databases", but will not be able see table "a" with a "show tables".  But that same user can see basic procedure info with a "show procedure status".

This is for auditing and I would like to have the audit process as obscured as possible.  If a user is granted execute on a procedure must that user have the ability to see the procedure? And must they be able to see the database that the procedure touches?

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of the procedure or if you have access to mysql.proc table you can see the definition of the procedure as stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-procedure.html).

So you would create the procedure as super and set DEFINER CURRENT_USER (so the procedure executes as super). Then make sure super has access to the table but that no one else does. That should protect both the table and the source but leave it possible to call on the procedure.

And it don't have to be super, can be any user that has access to the table.

Comment: Right.  So, the non-super user will not be able to see what the procedure does even with a show create procedure (if they aren't the procedure owner).  But they will be able to know that a procedure exists.  I don't think I can grant execute on a procedure without the user having the ability to know that the procedure exists.

Comment: I don't see how they could know it, the only way to know of procedures without actually KNOWING it is by reading mysql.proc and they can't. You'll tell them of course, that is the API against the database and you'll give them each proc and a description of it's parameters and resultsets.

Comment: Or, actually, you could probably do `SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`. I don't see any restrictions on that table.

Comment: They can see it that way or with <!-- language-all:  show procedure status lang-html -->. They can even do <!--SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE audit.login_trigger --> ! Because this table is for auditing user activity, I think I will have to give the the table and procedure some non-descriptive names to obscure their purpose.